# Applying rep() within groups through dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rep

I've been trying to replicate a binary output of 1 and 2 within groups.
I'd like to make use of `rep` and `dplyr`, but I can't seem to understand how to apply `rep` within groups. I've been able to do it by manually separating the groupings and specifying the correct range per group. I would like to know how `rep`could be applied using `dplyr`.

Here's a sample data.

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-02"),
                 loc =c("AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "CD", "CD", "CD", "CD", "CD", "CD", "CD", "CD", "CD", "CD"),
                 cat = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d"))
```

This is basically the code I run per grouping applied on the entire dataset.

```
df$type <- rep(1:2,nrow(df)/2)
```

As you can see, the output disregards the column `cat`. `cat b & d` should have started at 1.

```
         date loc cat type
1  2017-01-01  AB   a    1
2  2017-01-01  AB   a    2
3  2017-01-01  AB   a    1
4  2017-01-01  AB   b    2
5  2017-01-01  AB   b    1
6  2017-01-01  AB   b    2
7  2017-01-01  AB   b    1
8  2017-01-02  AB   b    2
9  2017-01-02  CD   c    1
10 2017-01-02  CD   c    2
11 2017-01-02  CD   c    1
12 2017-01-02  CD   c    2
13 2017-01-02  CD   c    1
14 2017-01-02  CD   d    2
15 2017-01-02  CD   d    1
16 2017-01-02  CD   d    2
17 2017-01-02  CD   d    1
```

UPDATE:
Here's the desired output.

```
        date loc cat type
1  2017-01-01  AB   a    1
2  2017-01-01  AB   a    2
3  2017-01-01  AB   a    1
4  2017-01-01  AB   b    1
5  2017-01-01  AB   b    2
6  2017-01-01  AB   b    1
7  2017-01-01  AB   b    2
8  2017-01-02  AB   b    1
9  2017-01-02  CD   c    1
10 2017-01-02  CD   c    2
11 2017-01-02  CD   c    1
12 2017-01-02  CD   c    2
13 2017-01-02  CD   c    1
14 2017-01-02  CD   d    1
15 2017-01-02  CD   d    2
16 2017-01-02  CD   d    1
17 2017-01-02  CD   d    2
```

Comment: In base, `df$type <- ave(seq(nrow(df)), df$cat, FUN = function(x){rep(1:2, length.out = length(x))})` or if you sort by `cat` first, `unlist(lapply(table(df$cat), function(x){rep(1:2, length.out = x)}))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `cat` is the only relevant grouping variable here (not date and loc), you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>%
    group_by(cat) %>%
    mutate(type = rep(1:2, length.out = length(cat)))
# Output:
         date    loc    cat  type
       <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <int>
1  2017-01-01     AB      a     1
2  2017-01-01     AB      a     2
3  2017-01-01     AB      a     1
4  2017-01-01     AB      b     1
5  2017-01-01     AB      b     2
6  2017-01-01     AB      b     1
7  2017-01-01     AB      b     2
8  2017-01-02     AB      b     1
9  2017-01-02     CD      c     1
10 2017-01-02     CD      c     2
11 2017-01-02     CD      c     1
12 2017-01-02     CD      c     2
13 2017-01-02     CD      c     1
14 2017-01-02     CD      d     1
15 2017-01-02     CD      d     2
16 2017-01-02     CD      d     1
17 2017-01-02     CD      d     2
18 2017-01-02     CD      d     1
```

Comment: You could use just `length.out = n()`