# Expand a data frame with rep in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/325548) expands a data frame of counts into a 0/1 data frame.  It looks something like this:

```
# compact representation
df <- tibble(
  treatment_status = c("treatment", "no_treatment"),
  disease = c(55, 42),
  no_disease = c(67,34))

# manually expanded representation
df_expanded <- tibble(
  disease_status = c(1, 1, 0, 0), 
  treatment_status = rep(c("treatment", "control"), 2)) %>%
  .[c(rep(1, 55), rep(2, 42), rep(3, 67), rep(4, 34)), ]
```

Suppose I wanted to do this in a more automated fashion depending on several variables (although for this example I'll use just treatment status), using dplyr.

I came up with this ugly hack:

```
# terribly awkward, but will work
df_expanded2 <- data.frame()
for (idx in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  row <- df[idx,]
  df_expanded2 <- bind_rows(
    df_expanded2,
    data.frame(treatment_status=row$treatment_status,
               disease_status=rep(1, row$disease)),
    data.frame(treatment_status=row$treatment_status,
               disease_status=rep(0, row$no_disease))
  )
}
```

Is there a neater way to do this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462154/applying-rep-within-groups-through-dplyr) seems similar, but I could not see how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier option is to reshape to 'long' format for the 'disease', 'no_disease' columns, convert the column to binary with `==` and `+`, then use `uncount` on the 'value' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = disease:no_disease, names_to = 'disease_status') %>% 
  mutate(disease_status = +(disease_status == 'disease')) %>% 
  uncount(value)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 198 x 2
#   treatment_status disease_status
#   <chr>                     <int>
# 1 treatment                     1
# 2 treatment                     1
# 3 treatment                     1
# 4 treatment                     1
# 5 treatment                     1
# 6 treatment                     1
# 7 treatment                     1
# 8 treatment                     1
# 9 treatment                     1
#10 treatment                     1
# … with 188 more rows
```